# How to generate "label data" In CustomDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am currently using Inception for a multi-class classification task,

but I have significant confusion and misunderstandings regarding label data.In the past, I used to convert mask files to one-hot encoding and use them as inputs.

I have searched many articles, and they mentioned various feature encoding methods and the reasons for using one-hot encoding, but none of them discussed how to generate these label data.

Below is the code I used in the past to read mask files in the custom data generator

```
class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes))

        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):
            image = np.load(image_path)
            label = np.load(label_path)  #label data
            label_grayscale = np.mean(label, axis=-1)
            min_val = label_grayscale.min()
            max_val = label_grayscale.max()
            scaled_label = (label_grayscale - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)  # Scale to [0, 1]
            scaled_label = (scaled_label * (self.n_classes - 1)).astype(int)  # Scale to [0, n_classes-1]
            label_one_hot = to_categorical(scaled_label, num_classes=self.n_classes)

            X[i,] = image
            y[i,] = label_one_hot
        return X, y
```

As for how to generate the label data , it could be produced through code? Or using tools like Labelme? Or generated from mask files? Or even manually inputted?